# Query to select a object with two exact records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following table in MySQL:

**some_table**

```
user_id | obj_id
-----------------
5       | 1
6       | 1
7       | 2
8       | 2
```

Now I need a Query, which will get me the obj_id, if this obj_id has both `user_id = 5` and `user_id = 6` (in the example above it is `obj_id=1`).

Is something like this possible with MySQL?

Comment: What have you tried?  And do **both** user ID's have to exist?  How do you get / know the user ID's?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One method uses `group by` and `having`:

```
select obj_id
from some_table t
where user_id in (5, 6)
group by obj_id
having count(distinct user_id) = 2;
```

Comment: Clever.  I was thinking `IN`, and `GROUP BY`, but wasn't sure how to force all to match.  `HAVING` the count match is perfect.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactlly what I was looking for. Thank you very much. I´ll mark your answer as correct in 10m (can´t right now).

Answer (score 2):

As @GordonLinoff already provided a better solution.

But this is one of the possible way to get your expected result using `INTERSECT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT obj_id FROM @TEST WHERE user_id = 5
INTERSECT
SELECT DISTINCT obj_id FROM @TEST WHERE user_id = 6
```

---

Sample execution:

```
CREATE TABLE some_table (`user_id` INT, obj_id INT);

INSERT INTO some_table (`user_id`, obj_id) VALUES 
(5, 1),
(6, 1),
(7, 2),
(8, 2),
(5, 3),
(6, 4);

SELECT DISTINCT obj_id FROM some_table WHERE `user_id` = 5
INTERSECT
SELECT DISTINCT obj_id FROM some_table WHERE `user_id` = 6
```

Result will be `1`.